# SequenceFile is not created in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a MapReduce job to test some calculations. I split my input into maps so that each map does part of the calculus, the result will be a list of (X,y) pairs which I want to flush into a SequenceFile.

The map part goes well but when the Reducer kicks in I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://172.16.199.132:9000/user/hduser/FractalJob_1452257628594_410365359/out/reduce-out`.

Another observation would be that this error appears only when I use more then  map.

**UPDATED**  Here is my Mapper and Reducer code.

```
public static class RasterMapper extends Mapper<IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
        private int imageS;
        private static Complex mapConstant;


        @Override
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
            imageS = context.getConfiguration().getInt("image.size", -1);

            mapConstant = new Complex(context.getConfiguration().getDouble("constant.re", -1),
                    context.getConfiguration().getDouble("constant.im", -1));

        }

        @Override
        public void map(IntWritable begin, IntWritable end, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


            for (int x = (int) begin.get(); x < end.get(); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < imageS; y++) {

                    float hue = 0, brighness = 0;
                    int icolor = 0;
                    Complex z = new Complex(2.0 * (x - imageS / 2) / (imageS / 2),
                            1.33 * (y - imageS / 2) / (imageS / 2));

                    icolor = startCompute(generateZ(z), 0);

                    if (icolor != -1) {
                        brighness = 1f;
                    }


                    hue = (icolor % 256) / 255.0f;

                    Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1f, brighness);
                    try {
                        context.write(new IntWritable(x + y * imageS), new IntWritable(color.getRGB()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }
            }

        }


        private static Complex generateZ(Complex z) {
            return (z.times(z)).plus(mapConstant);
        }

        private static int startCompute(Complex z, int color) {

            if (z.abs() > 4) {
                return color;
            } else if (color >= 255) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                color = color + 1;
                return startCompute(generateZ(z), color);
            }
        }

    }

    public static class ImageReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, WritableComparable<?>, Writable> {
        private SequenceFile.Writer writer;

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            writer.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
            Path outDir = new Path(conf.get(FileOutputFormat.OUTDIR));
            Path outFile = new Path(outDir, "pixels-out");

            Option optPath = SequenceFile.Writer.file(outFile);
            Option optKey = SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(IntWritable.class);
            Option optVal = SequenceFile.Writer.valueClass(IntWritable.class);
            Option optCom = SequenceFile.Writer.compression(CompressionType.NONE);
            try {
                writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf, optCom, optKey, optPath, optVal);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void reduce (IntWritable key,  Iterable<IntWritable>  value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                try{

                    writer.append(key, value.iterator().next());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
```

I hope you guys can help me out.
Thank you!

**EDIT**:

```
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0
```

Looking better at the logs I noticed I think that the issue come from the way I feed my data to the maps.I split my image size into several sequence files so that the maps can read it from there and compute the colors for the pixels in that area.

This is the way I create the files :

```
try {
    int offset = 0;

    // generate an input file for each map task
    for (int i = 0; i < mapNr; ++i) {

        final Path file = new Path(input, "part" + i);

        final IntWritable begin = new IntWritable(offset);
        final IntWritable end = new IntWritable(offset + imgSize / mapNr);
        offset = (int) end.get();

        Option optPath = SequenceFile.Writer.file(file);
        Option optKey = SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(IntWritable.class);
        Option optVal = SequenceFile.Writer.valueClass(IntWritable.class);
        Option optCom = SequenceFile.Writer.compression(CompressionType.NONE);
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf, optCom, optKey, optPath, optVal);
        try {
            writer.append(begin, end);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Wrote input for Map #" + i);
    }
```

Log file:

```
 16/01/10 19:06:04 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /172.16.199.132:8032
16/01/10 19:06:07 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
16/01/10 19:06:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:4
16/01/10 19:06:08 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1452444283951_0007
16/01/10 19:06:08 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1452444283951_0007
16/01/10 19:06:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://172.16.199.132:8088/proxy/application_1452444283951_0007/
16/01/10 19:06:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1452444283951_0007
16/01/10 19:06:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1452444283951_0007 running in uber mode : false
16/01/10 19:06:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/01/10 19:06:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:06:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:06:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:06:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:07:07 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 25% reduce 0%
16/01/10 19:07:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
16/01/10 19:07:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:07:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:07:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:07:32 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/01/10 19:07:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:07:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:07:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
16/01/10 19:07:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
16/01/10 19:07:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1452444283951_0007_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
16/01/10 19:07:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/01/10 19:07:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1452444283951_0007 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1452444283951_0007_m_000003
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

16/01/10 19:07:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 40
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=0
        FILE: Number of bytes written=3048165
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=765
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
        HDFS: Number of read operations=12
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=9
        Failed reduce tasks=2
        Killed reduce tasks=1
        Launched map tasks=12
        Launched reduce tasks=3
        Other local map tasks=8
        Data-local map tasks=4
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=239938
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=34189
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=239938
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=34189
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=239938
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=34189
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=245696512
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=35009536
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=3
        Map output records=270000
        Map output bytes=2160000
        Map output materialized bytes=2700018
        Input split bytes=441
        Combine input records=0
        Spilled Records=270000
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=538
        CPU time spent (ms)=5520
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=643928064
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2537975808
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=408760320
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=324
Constructing image...
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://172.16.199.132:9000/user/hduser/FractalJob_1452445557585_342741171/out/pixels-out
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1752)
    at FractalJob.generateFractal(FractalJob.j..
```

This is the configuration:

```
conf.setInt("image.size", imgSize);
    conf.setDouble("constant.re", FractalJob.constant.re());
    conf.setDouble("constant.im", FractalJob.constant.im());

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
    job.setJobName(FractalJob.class.getSimpleName());

    job.setJarByClass(FractalJob.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

    job.setMapperClass(RasterMapper.class);

    job.setReducerClass(ImageReducer.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    job.setSpeculativeExecution(false);

    final Path input = new Path(filePath, "in");
    final Path output = new Path(filePath, "out");

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, input);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about creating your own sequence files. MapReduce has an output format that does it automatically.

So, in your driver class you would use:

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
```

and then in the reducer you'd write:

```
context.write(key, values.iterator().next());
```

and delete all of the `setup` method.

As a kind of aside, it doesn't look like you need a reducer at all. If you're not doing any calculations in the reducer and you're not doing anything with grouping (which I presume you're not), then why not just delete it? `job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class)` will write your mapper output to sequence files.

If you do only want one output file, set

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```

And provided your final data isn't > 1 block size, you'll get the output you want.

It's worth noting that you're currently only outputting one value per key - you should ensure that you want that, and include a loop in the reducer to iterate over the values if you don't.

Comment: Sorry for reposting the question , just update this one

Comment: Updated the question. One reducer should force everything into a single file.

Comment: Hey sorry for late response. I did as you said, still logger still says `Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0.` and `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException.` I will add my configuration above maybe that is the problem.